# Error Redirection to restful with special chars

Tags: apache, get, url-encoding

When I redirect using GET method 
      $uid=urlencode($uid);
      header(Location: "http://www.example.com/teldom.me.jersey/index.html?userid=$uid&lang=$lang");'

to java restful service runnig in tomcat with url encoded special chars, a browser display:

```
The requested URL /teldom.me.jersey/rest/conf/EBo6Fp3Od00urp6TIF/3gGcrsg== was not found on this server
```

Apache Error log

```
[Sat Nov 23 00:13:02 2013] [error] [client xx.yy.65.87] File does not exist: /home/bmil/Dokumenti/webapps/cdn-cgi, referer: http://www.example.com/teldom.me.jersey/index.html?userid=EBo6Fp3Od00urp6TIF%2F3gGcrsg%3D%3D
```

In javascript I send ajax request to restful service using

```
http('POST', submitTo, ajax_response, document.form1);
```

This is a ColdFusion API for AJAX.  (v 2.6.0)

The problem is when ajax  send request with special html chars %2F to Tomcat

Following is from tomcat localhost access log file:

```
xx.yy.65.87 - - [23/Nov/2013:23:17:14 +0100] "GET /teldom.me.jersey/index.html?userid=EBo6Fp3Od00urp6TIF%2F3gGcrsg%3D%3D&lang= HTTP/1.1" 304 -

xx.yy.65.87 - - [23/Nov/2013:23:09:38 +0100] "POST /teldom.me.jersey/rest/conf/E6iKbMC8jTFz4JifHDdqogj3?nocache=1385244552675 HTTP/1.1" 200 288
8
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved!

```
 $find_entities = array("/","&", "?");
 if(strpos($id, $find_entities) !== false)
 {
   $uid=urlencode ($uid);
   $uid=urlencode ($uid);
 } else {
      $uid=urlencode ($uid);
 }

  header("Location: http://www.example.com/teldom.me.jersey/index.html?userid=$uid");
```